# How to make a table that fills the complete page

Tags: html, css

I will like to create a fluid layout as the following that fills a whole page (width:100%;height:100%).

```
+----+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----|    |
|    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----|    |
|    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+
```

Inside of each cell I would like to have a div width rounded bordes and would like to have cellspacing between the cells.  Each of the cells needs to be fixed size with (overflow:hidden).

Any ideas on the best way to do this?

(Update)

I've tried doing a table but can't control rows and/or cell's height growing out of proportion even when the td and div inside it have a fixed percentage height and overflow hidden.

I've also tried with 9 divs floated left and 1 div floated right.  If no margin or padding is set it works great.  As soon as padding and margin are set (in percentage) and compensating the widths and height (also in percentage).  Nothings seems to align.

Which of these two should I continue to develop further?

Comment: Tables are bad for layout: http://phrogz.net/css/WhyTablesAreBadForLayout.html

Comment: Have a read on CSS positioning

Comment: Would appreciate some explanation on the down votes.  Having a fluid width and height layout seems a very legitimate question.

Comment: Not with table, no... (I wasn't downvoting btw)

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
    html, body, table { width:100%; height:100%; }
    td { width:25%; height:33%; }
    div.round { width:100%; height:100%; background:blue; border-radius:5px; overflow:hidden; }
</style>


<table>
    <tr>
        <td><div class="round"></div></td>
        <td><div class="round"></div></td>
        <td><div class="round"></div></td>
        <td rowspan="3"><div class="round"></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div class="round"></div></td>
        <td><div class="round"></div></td>
        <td><div class="round"></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div class="round"></div></td>
        <td><div class="round"></div></td>
        <td><div class="round"></div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I just tried this and when onf of the divs grows very large is breaks the layout.  It is not enforcing the height 33% on the td.